# Cloudy hot water out of 1 sink in the whole house

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

There is one sink in our house that when you turn on hot water the water comes out very cloudy.  It is in a upstairs bathroom and it is part of a double sink, the other works fine.  Picture of the water below.

Also the hot and cold water handles are hard to turn, what could cause that?

The water flow is weak compared to the other sinks, does the faucet need replacing?

What causes the cloudy water (if the water stays in the cup, it does clear up)?

[image: Hot cloudy water]

Comment: Does the water clear upon sitting? I sometimes get cloudy water out of one fixture, but it clears upon sitting and I just use it. I think the fixture or the supply lines to it are mineralized and shedding mineral deposits in small particles.

Comment: Yes, it does clear up, is it going to do this forever then?

Comment: I just noticed the same issue. But this only happens on one of the sinks. On Another bathroom sink the hot water runs clear. Kind of disturbing if you ask me.