# Cloudy hot water from bathroom sink

Tags: hot-water

I have 2 bathroom sinks on the 2nd floor (not in the same room).
One of them produces a cloudy (almost milky) white hot water. The other was runs clear hot water. Could this be an issue?

[This appears to be a similar issue.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131385/cloudy-hot-water-out-of-1-sink-in-the-whole-house)

Comment: It's often simply aeration. Does it clear up after a minute or two?

Comment: No, i had it on for several minutes - but still coudy. I did reduce the hot water valve.This helps minimize the cloudiness (there is less hot water coming out). I know this isnt a solution though.

Comment: I meant if you let it stand. If it's being aerated by the plumbing, letting it run won't change that.

Comment: Aerated by the plumbing? Does the hot tube aerate as opposed to the cold tube? The cold water runs perfectly clear. So id imagine its not an aeration issue.

Comment: I think it is fine mineral particles. I see this sometime in one of our faucets. If I let it sit the water clears. I have not tried to see if there is particulate matter settling to the bottom of a container, but I think that is what I see. I use this water anyway.